# how can i retrieve value in JSON string in lambda python3

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I'm developing an AWS lambda function that is triggered from an event bridge and then putting another event using python
but struggling to retrieve a value from a variable in the Json string

below is the code

```
import json, boto3

client = boto3.client('events')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

testV2_dict={  
 "K1" : event['e1'] ,
"K2" : event['e2'] 
}

#converting python to json as (put_event - Details) section is expecting json
testV2=json.dumps(testV2_dict)

response = client.put_events(
         Entries=
          [
            {
             "DetailType": "test",
             "Source": "test",
             "Detail": "{ \"testK\": \"testV\",\"testK2\": \""+ testV2 +"\" }"
           }
          ]
        )
```

tried to add Details on different ways,
`"Detail": "{ \"testK\": \"testV\",\"testK2\": \""+ testV2 +"\" }"` and still getting error as `Malformated Details`
and if i deleted the ++, I'm getting word `testV2` itself not the value from the above

How can I retrieve the value of testV2 in the Details inside the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough escaping in there.  If `testV2` is supposed to be a JSON string emebedded in a JSON string embedded in as JSON string, then you need more string escapes.  I would let `json.dumps` handle that:

```
import json
event = {'e1': 99, 'e2': 101}

testV2_dict={  
 "K1" : event['e1'] ,
 "K2" : event['e2'] 
}

testV2=json.dumps(testV2_dict)

detail = {
    "testK": "testV",
    "testK2": testV2
}

Entries= [
    {
     "DetailType": "test",
     "Source": "test",
     "Detail": json.dumps(detail),
   }
]

print(Entries)
```

Output:

```
[{'DetailType': 'test', 'Source': 'test', 'Detail': '{"testK": "testV", "testK2": "{\\"K1\\": 99, \\"K2\\": 101}"}'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to do any thing the output of boto3 client has always been in JSON string.

Comment: You missed the point.  The nested content is also an embedded JSON string, and it was not formatted correctly.